# How do I link my MS Visual Studio project against OpenSSL static libraries?

Tags: static, linker, openssl, hmac

Before starting on this project, I had the false impression I was proficient in coding and using Visual Studio 2010. I realize now I was under just full of myself.

My platform is development box is 64bit Windows 7, but I need to build for both 64 and 32 bit platforms.  I'm using VS 2010 and OpenSSL 1.0.0e, though if need be, I can use another one.  I'm trying to create a static library (*.lib) that will be included into a larger project by other developers.  The *.lib seems to compile, but obviously things are not all well since the test program breaks.

I cannot use *.dlls with my program, this has come from on high, therefore I've been trying to statically link my library to libeay32.lib and ssleay32.lib.  I've only just begun and like to start slow when using something new, so the only two functions I'm trying to call from SSL are HMAC and EVP_sha512:

`HMAC(EVP_sha512(), key, keyLen, lpBufferAddr, dwCurBufSize, hashOut, &len);`

I acknowledge I may be doing it entirely wrong, but there you have it. Honestly, the only thing I need are the crypto functions, and HMAC functions. I could probably use something else, but I've been told to use OpenSSL. Anyway, moving on....

When building the test program that links to my library project (which in turn links to the two OpenSSL libraries), I get the following linking errors:

```
error LINK2019: unresolved external symbol _HMAC@28 referenced in function "public: int _thiscall etc"
error LINK2019: unresolved external symbol _EVP_sha512@28 referenced in function "public: int _thiscall etc"
```

I include both libraries in "Additional Dependencies", and have included their directory in "Additional Library Dependencies".

Can anyone help me with this? I've been pouring over this and have come to the unfortunate conclusion I'm a dunce.  Creating static libs from OpenSSL was difficult enough for me, I  admit, and I'm not even convinced I succeeded with x64.  Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSL is C-based library and is compiled with /Gd option. All the functions are with __cdecl calling convention.

Add __cdecl before the functions which you are using. (Note that there is no need to recompile the library after adding __cdecl since the library is compiled with this option).

e.g. if you are using SSL_connect

```
 int __cdecl SSL_connect(SSL * ssl);
```

I think, it will solve your problem.

In few cases, you many need to wrap the function declaration under extern "C". But as far as I know, in this case, you should not need to do this.